# Can't implement the W3Schools slideshow in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to edit my Bootstrap and I want to add more stuff then what it already has but it isn't working.

I tried to add a slideshow, but it is completely white, only the arrows to change the image are blue.

I know part of it is working because when I click to change the image, the dimensions of the page change (I only have 1 photo, the others 2 links are for photos that don't exist).

I copied the W3Schools code and pasted it in the bootstrap page, is something in the bootstrap file, putting everything white?

Here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="~/Photo/Test1.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: show your code pls

Comment: please update your question with the code

Comment: That is the slideshow code

Comment: looks fine for me here

Comment: @LelioFaieta  Exactly, but when I implement it with the bootstrap file, everything is white. The photo doesnt appear, only white. However, the dimensions change, which means that the mechanics are working

Comment: post the bootstrap code which you have tried

Comment: @SaiManoj it is the second box in the question. I just added it to the end of the bootstrap, I don't know if I should have done anything different.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the tutorial you are following and intend to expand on.

Comment: I want to use [this slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). The bootstrap has 7000 lines of code, but its [this one](https://bootswatch.com/3/yeti/)

Comment: check the below snippet. I have answered your question with working snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question, when you add bootstrap to the code the images are being displayed in white color as your code is getting effected by `class="fade"` as it's overlapping with `bootstrap fade class`. Use a different class name

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade-in {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade-in">
      <div class="numbertext">
        1 / 3
      </div><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">
        Caption Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade-in">
      <div class="numbertext">
        2 / 3
      </div><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">
        Caption Two
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade-in">
      <div class="numbertext">
        3 / 3
      </div><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">
        Caption Three
      </div>
    </div><!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div><br>
  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The most logical reason seems to be that the path of the image being displayed in carousel/slideshow is not correct.

When the page is loaded, open the developer tools and in the html, search for `Photo/Test1.png`, there would be a path in the `src` tag.

Verify that the path is correct. Open the link in a new tab to verify that the image in-fact is loading at the URL and do the same for other images you are using.

You can also try to use absolute paths as the image `src` attribute, for example:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg
```

If that loads the images than it surely is an issue with path you are using.

Comment: It didnt work. The other answer was correct. Thank you a lot for your time sir.

Comment: That's odd. This solution worked perfectly fine for me.